# change column names in time arrays in julia

Tags: julia

I have a matrix in Julia composed by by multiple TimeArrays. The first column is dates and there are several other columns?
Is it possible to change the names of the columns keeping the TimeArray formats?

Thank you very much.

Comment: *"matrix composed by multiple TimeArrays."*  Be more specific.  Post a reduced example.  What have you tried?  [Help: How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thanks for the reply I managed to to solve the problem!